# Authors Page : A page of authors

Tags: users, page-template, author, list-authors, author-template

I'm looking for a way to create a parent authors page and then use the `author.php` for the individual author pages.
I've been out of the loop (no pun) for a couple months and am wondering the best way to do it.

Comment: What do you need in this "parent" page? why not use regular page?

Comment: I'd like to create a page of authors and have them link to individual author's pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First, Explaining Loops

You're dealing with two kinds of "loops."  The first is a loop in PHP, the second is a loop in WordPress.

### Loop in PHP

kaiser gave you some code that will generate a list of authors on your site.  You can iterate through this list and print information on the screen.

```
// Fetch an array of authors from WordPress and store it in the $authors variable
$authors = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'role' => 'editor',
    'fields' => array(
        'first_name',
        'last_name'
    )
) );

// For each author in $authors, we display their name and a link to their author archive page
foreach ( $authors as $author ) {

    // EXAMPLE: display author first & last name
    echo "{$author->first_name} {$author->last_name}";

    echo get_author_posts_url( $author->ID );
}
```

If you have two members on your site in the "editor" role, the `WP_User_Query()` call will return a PHP array with two objects in it, each object representing an author.  You *loop* through that array and write out the information from each object in turn.

### The WordPress Loop

WordPress calls its standard post system "[The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)."  It's a standard set of code that's used in each page template, index template, archive template, etc to display post content.  The standard Loop looks something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    // Code for individual posts goes here

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Inside the Loop (the `// Code for individual posts goes here` part) you can use special functions like `the_title()`, `the_permalink()`, `the_content()`, etc.

## What You Need

You need two pages in your theme.  First, you need an `author.php`, as you already indicated in your question.  This will display an archive of each post written by a specific author.  For example, `http://yoursite.url/author/john-doe` will list all posts written by an author with the slug, "john-doe."

You also need to create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates).  I would recommend something called `author-parent.php` or something along those lines.  This template file should use `WP_User_Query()` to fetch a list of users, display those user names, and display links to individual user archive pages.

Then, you need to create a page in WordPress and assign this custom template to that page.  When you visit that page in the browser, WordPress will load your custom template and print out the data you're looking for.

## Now, a Word on *Rules*

The WordPress Answers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site.  You need to ask clear, specific questions with as much detail as possible.  If people ask you clarifying questions in comments, those are intended to help you refine, clarify, and further flesh out your question.

Don't just continue to leave comments.  *Go back and edit your original question* to add extra information.  If we can't figure out what you're asking, we can't answer your question.

When any question or answer accumulates more than 20 comments in a short period of time, it is automatically flagged by the system for moderator attention.  That many comments means something is *wrong*.

Comments like:

> No helps for newbs? Sad...

And:

> Sad... I thought I would actually get some help here...

Do nothing to clarify or contribute to the conversation.  They're off topic, create noise, and make it more difficult for the *volunteers* on the site to help you.

Please take a moment to review [the FAQs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) for the site.  They outline how to ask questions on the site and participate in the community.  I have no doubt that you can find answers to your questions here.  Just remember, if we're responding to your questions with "I don't understand" or if there are long comment strings like above, then you might need to rephrase your question.  Or just give an example of what you're trying to accomplish; even if you don't know the right technical terms for what you're doing, explaining it in plain enough language will often be enough.

Comment: Thank you.
As for my comments, those were in response to kaiser's comments on my supposed laziness. 
I hope they do create noise... if there are "volunteers" then I would hope that they would realize that they don't HAVE to help. Me expressing my sadness for him not helping me understand the difference between PHP and the WP Codex and his smug ideals that we should ALL know EVERYTHING,doesn't help anyone. BC I thought this was a WP issue, I posted it in WPSE. Now that someone has actually explained this to me, I can move on.

Comment: The core of your question is a WP issue, so this was definitely the right place for it. Just a disconnect over terminology. Glad you've got everything sorted out. :-)

Comment: @hoss9009 Just for the record: _»This Q does not show any research effort;«_ is what you read when you hover over the down vote arrow for a Q. No one expects that you _know everything_. But we expect you to do research on equal height to the difficulty of your Q. If you're asking something, get an answer that fits and then are not able to implement it, then you asked something _above_ your research effort. The only reason for all the patience here is that we a) want to keep the system friendly and b) let it become _the ressource_ and b) you're new. So, please keep this in mind for further Qs.

Comment: Wow @kaiser, I'm glad you know exactly what I've done to solve this problem. Assuming doesn't help me... at all. 
I have researched my issue and have found two, just TWO articles with information on them: [1](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/06/09/doing-more-with-gravatars-authors-template-page) & [2](http://wpsplash.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-authors-page/)
Obviously, Justin Tadlock was a little helpful, but doesn't help w/ avatars exactly how I would like. The WPSplash ex is a lil' weak. I could assume you lack brain function, but I won't because that would be rude, so I won't.

Comment: @EAMann thank you for your support and only commenting to help and be productive, unlike others.

Answer (score 1):

### Use internal/built-in classes

WP got …

- the [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) class. You can easily query for users of a role and return only those fields, that you actually need.
- [`wp_list_authors();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors)

#### Example code

```
$authors = new WP_User_Query( array(
     'role' => 'editor',
     'fields' => array(
          'first_name',
          'last_name'
     )
) );
```

Then just loop through your results (the authors) in a custom template file and assign this to a normal page.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Editors Page
*/

// Query goes here

foreach ( $authors as $author )
{
    // Inspect the author data
    var_dump( $author );

    // EXAMPLE: display author first & last name
    echo "{$author->first_name} {$author->last_name}";

    // Link to author posts @see        http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url
    get_author_posts_url( $author->ID );
}
```

Comment: Kaiser... thanks. But I'm not sure exactly how to use this... sorry im kind of a dummy when it comes to the loop. 
How do I create a loop based off of this info. Basically, I want to treat the author.php template as a profile page.

Comment: And I'd like to create a page that displays all the users.

Comment: See Update. Basically, I can just tell you to spend some hours on php.net and similar and learn basic php. This will avoid such Qs and help you searching and implementing much easier, which is over all a time saver for you.

Comment: No helps for newbs? Sad...

Comment: Sure there is help for "newbs". On StackOverflow.com or php.net for example. But WPSE is a Q/A for WordPress, not for general php Questions.

Comment: All I'm asking for is a loop that will show the authors... I noticed in the Codex that (for author.php) you need just a bit of code PRIOR to the loop. Is this what you're giving me?

Comment: I'm giving you a full blown (and fast) User Query that then has an `foreach` loop afterwards. It's close to impossible to answer your question and then explain every single bit when you can't even read php and know nothing about the basics of the WP templating mechanism. Explaining all this would exceed the Q. That's why I told you to read about the php basics on php.net or some beginners tutorial. This will _save endless amounts of time on both side_. You're spending more time asking as you'd need to learn the basics. Period.

Comment: Can I use the top portion of code just like I would use `WP_Query`?

Comment: No, you can't use `if ( have_posts() );` etc. You can use it like you'd use `get_posts()`. That's the last thing I'm now writing here. Even the system is pushing to stop discussion here.

Comment: Sad... I thought I would actually get some help here...

Comment: You _got_ help. ↑ is all you need _from the WP side of things_. You're not asking for help. Your Question is "Write the template for me".

Comment: No... I don't understand what to do with something that is extremely vague to me. I asked what to do with the code and I was told: "good luck..."  
There's a difference between being needy and not being knowledgeable of how to implement the code.

Comment: If this were a loop issue, I'd be able to figure to it out.

Comment: [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) _IS_ a loop! So: Where's your problem? Loop through it, `var_dump()` the contents of each single `$author` and `echo`/display whatever you want to display in your template.

Comment: Ok, I extended the example. If you now can't get around, then I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you... still not understanding it, but no one is MAKING you comment.

Comment: Also, after searching WP.org, google, stackexchange, and a number of other useful sites, there's very little info on how to use `WP_User_Query`.

Comment: there is everything you need here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Comment: @Bainternet - Thanks. (And btw: It's already linked in the answer... :)

Comment: @kaiser i guess i missed it somehow.

Comment: @Bainternet Thanks, but I don't get how to use it within the confines of the loop.
I don't see how to integrate it with something this: 
`<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <div class="post">
  <h2 class="section-header">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </h2>
  <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
 </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`
Sorry I know WP themes, but I didn't have any formal training. I hope that's not against the rules.

Comment: You're mixing up loops with "The Loop" in WordPress.  You need to loop (iterate) through a list of authors using the code @kaiser has given you to display their information. This loop has nothing to do with the post "Loop." They are completely separate things. If you want to use both, *please edit your question to explain* **exactly** *what it is you're trying to accomplish.* In the mean time, I am locking comments on this answer. This is **not** a discussion forum.