# resolve /author/ to a page or archive (of all authors) template

Tags: rewrite-rules, author-template

I know how to query the users and create a list of authors and can accomplish this in a page template, much like is described here:
[Authors Page : A page of authors](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43582/authors-page-a-page-of-authors)

my question is then....

is there a way so that i can have www.site.com/author resolve to the page where I am displaying a list of all authors?

I just attempted to create a static page w/ an 'author' slug and it unsurprisingly 404s, I presume b/c WP is expecting something to follow 'author' and nothing is.

Do I create an endpoint (rewrite stuff is still complex for me) or can I intercept the template_redirection and send it to my custom page?   Any push in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use code similar to setup the rewrite rules:

```
function ex_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $feed_rules = array(
        'author/?$'    =>  'index.php?author_page=author_page'
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'ex_rewrite' );
```

followed by code to add the `author_page` as a valid query var:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');
function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'author_page';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
```

You can then check for this in your `functions.php`, and call `get_template_part` to call your 'authors' template and list the authors out, e.g.:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_page_template_redirect');
fnction custom_page_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    $custom_page = $wp_query->query_vars['author_page'];
    if ($custom_page == 'author_page') {
        get_template_part('authorlisting');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now all you need is an 'authorlisting.php' in your theme, and to flush your permalinks so the new rule takes effect. I wouldn't add anything to the end of that rewrite rule however as it may interfere with the existing author rules, so be wary. Also you may have issues with pagination, but all I can say is to test it out.

Comment: so the answer is both?  :)  thanks for the reply Tom. index.php?author_page=author_page does trigger the author listing template.. but /author still 404s. i did re-save my permainks.

Comment: try variations in the rewrite rules additon such as /author/ author/ /author etc

Comment: I've also added a return statement, all filters should return what they're passed ( albeit modified )

Comment: yes must return, or pass $wp_rewrite by reference, or add_action('generate_rewrite_rules','ex_rewrite'); where it is passed by reference automatically.  that was step 1. step 2 was changing the rule match to : 'author/?$' . i var_dumped the $wp_rewrite->rules and saw the /$ character at the end of custom post type archives.  and the last part was reversing the union of arrays to $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules .  this puts the new rule at the top so it is processed first. also can do add_rewrite_rule() on the init hook. all work. can you edit your answer so I can mark it as correct? thanks!

Comment: cursory testing of pagination makes me think we need a second rule to read the 'paged' parameter:  
add_rewrite_rule('author/?page/([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?author_page=author_page&paged=$matches[1]','top');  though i am lost on how to implement the rest of pagination (namely creating a 'next authors' style link b/c w/ posts you'd just use the paged var as the offset, but i don't think authors work that way) but i will leave that for another question.  thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, I'll make ammendments immediatley. Regarding pagination, your template will need to account for that since there will be no usable 'main query'. a WP_User_Query object with the appropriate parameters may be useful, but you'll need to pluck the pagination query vars out and pass them manually. It's all quite dependant on how you intend to implement the listing itself.

Comment: I've updated the answer, though if there are any more modifications you can suggest I'm happy to update it further. I may write a blogpost about this too, do you have a twitter account that I can credit you to?

Comment: thanks Tom. i'm @kathy_darling.  basically i'm looking to make the list of authors behave as if 'author' were a category and the authors were the posts.  found wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-list/ after the fact. will have to see what the plugin is doing for pagination